# Making the up to date Template my self

Tags: xetex, templates

Im trying to make my own template and run in to some od failures about outdated or deprecated packages. Most of my code i copyed from here so my question is:
Whats your sugestions to get a up to date template with my own font/color definitions for Headers sections and subsections?
Im running MacTex and use XeLaTeX.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Deprecated packages tend to point to a successor, use that. Outdated packages - do you mean they haven't been updated on CTAN (if so CTAN suggests similar packages which is probably the easiest way to find things) or is your local TeX distribution in need of an update (in which case update it). I think this question is too broad to be answered, if you have a specific package clash or want a specific thing then that's more the question to ask (with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228))

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I changed to lualatex and read abit more so now i came over those od messages....

Answer (score 1):

I'm using templates to write letters and contracts (being a lawyer). I'm using each of them every day. It turned out to be the easiest way to have short templates with just the structure, mainly settings of the documentclass, encoding, fonts and such basic things.

The rest is stored in code snippets, if necessary. OK, I simply don't forget to load array or booktabs for tabulars. But for pdfpages there is a code snippet to avoid forgetting `\pdfinclusioncopyfonts=1`.

Before I update my texlive-installation I have a look at the change log of the KOMA-script bundle, which I use for structure and which is really important. Changes here take some time, e.g. the switch from the documentclass scrlttr2 for letters to documentclass scrartcl plus the scrletter package.

So don't put a lot of stuff into your templates, rather keep them clean and lean. The rest of your code goes into code snippets, which are "optional", they depend on the need of your current project.

Thus you can see quite fast, why you get which error or warning. Read the message and have a look at the docu of the package: `texdoc packagename` on the command line / terminal will bring up the PDF.

Comment: Interessting! thanks for those inputs and the usecase!